# "Failed to open OSinstaller" on re-install MacOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, install

Running into a problem that says "Installer information on the recovery server is damaged" when trying to re-install MacOS (Sierra) on Macbook Air 2017. Most tutorials/"fixes" on Youtube/the internet tell me to change my system's date to like 2018, which doesn't fix anything..

The exact error in the install log tells me the following:

> `Failed to open OSInstaller because the installer is not trusted: Error Domain=PKProductErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={PKTrustlLevel=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d65522950 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147409654 "CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED" UserInfo={SecTrustResult=5, PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelExpiredCertificate, NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED}}}`

If anyone has experience with this or an idea how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps [this page](https://hammen.medium.com/the-apple-packagepocalypse-2019-edition-6e2d4bc0aa90) and [this one](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/heads-up-apple-s-installer-certificate-expires-today/m-p/144494) can give you some clues on solving the problem.

Comment: Make a bootable USB, use that bootable USB to install the OS.

Comment: The certificate issues were fixed a couple of years ago. You have an old installer. Fetch new from [Apple KB - How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT211683)